# Clarification on Apple version identification?

Tags: ipad, serial-number

I want to know the exact version of an older iPad.

After looking up the serial number, it states iPad2,2. I know it is a second generation iPad, but what does the number after the comma identify?

Does this mean this is iPad2 second generation, where iPad2,1 would be iPad2 first generation?

I thought the generation was the first number, so iPad1 is 1st generation, iPad2 is 2nd, and so on.

How do I properly identify iPad2,2 and other iPads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general statement regarding Model Identifiers (example: iPad1,1) is `first number indicates generation and the second number indicates variant`. However, there are many instances where simply reading the model identifier and trying to decode it cannot identify a device.

Comprehensive lists are available at [EveryI](http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-identifier.html) and [The iPhone Wiki](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models). Note that there are several instances of overlap (example: iPad1,1 for both WiFi and WiFi+3G models)

The [model/family/"A" number](http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-number-family-number.html) (example: A1234) may also be useful in identifying a given device (though some also overlap, such as A1395 for iPad2,1 and iPad2,4).

The [model/part/"M" number](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models) is even better, typically allowing identification of more specific detail.

The iPad2,2 specifically refers to the [iPad 2 WiFi+3G (GSM)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-2-wi-fi-gsm-att-a-gps-specs.html).